# Native SQL - How to set the schema and database names

Tags: sql, database, select, schema, native

Im using Native SQL from ABAP language. The query to get data is something like this

```
SELECT COUNT(ROWID) 
FROM <SCHEMANAME>.<TABLENAME>;@<DATABASENAME> 
INTO :localvariable
```

I want to somehow set the schemaname and database name as default so that i do not need to use them in the SELECTs later. Then i can only use the table name in the SELECT.

thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

There's no abap statement to do this.  The only possibility I can think of is to use your database provider's command to set the default schema.  For example, if you're using DB2 you could try something like:

```
EXEC SQL.
SET SCHEMA SCHEMANAME
END EXEC.
```